# Is it about time to add 'texlive-2021' tag?

Tags: discussion, tagging

Is it about time to add `texlive-2021` tag? There is already [one question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/612777/why-did-my-installation-of-texlive-2021-from-source-code-fail-on-ubuntu) concerning the newest distribution.

Comment: We don't necessarily need a tag for it, but you can of course just write that text (tags don't have to be pre-generated)